# FFmpeg potential mem leak like behavior points. Are there such?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, encoding, ffmpeg

So I mean like it tries to educate it self and collects some data... Are there any such points/feilds in encoding part of ffmpeg (that I hope can be disabeld)?

BTW: My problem is simple: I looked thrue out all my code. It seriosly looks like it is some part of my ffmpeg windows build leaks memory a littel... all the time while I am encoding... So I hope ffmpeg is just triing to learn so that I would be able to tell ti not to learn!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FFmpeg` libraries use a very object-oriented design. All memory allocated should be kept track of in the context structures and freed when the relevant context is destroyed. There may be some one-time allocation and initialization of constant global data which one could call a "leak", but I believe that was all replaced with `static const` tables to facilitate better use of shared memory and eliminate memory leaks associated with dynamic loading. If you really think it's leaking (and if you care), you need to use some memory debugging tools to identify where the leaks might be and coordinate finding/fixing them with the developers.

If what you mean is that during a single encode, memory usage grows slightly, this is probably normal and to be expected. It shouldn't be much, and the memory should all be released when the encoding context is freed.